# Add ESRI wayback WMTS service in ipyleaflet

Tags: python, leaflet, esri-leaflet, ipyleaflet

I'm struggling to use the ESRI wayback WMTS service in (ipy)leaflet.

I tried the options below but none of them worked.

Via wms

```py
from ipyleaflet import Map, basemaps, WMSLayer, TileLayer

wayback_url = 'https://wayback.maptiles.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/'
m = Map(basemap=basemaps.OpenStreetMap.Mapnik, center=(44.7814, 4.7174), zoom=16,
        scroll_wheel_zoom=True)
wms = WMSLayer(url=wayback_url, layers='WB_2021_R17')
m.add_layer(wms)
m
```

via `TileLayer`

```py
wmts = TileLayer(url='https://wayback.maptiles.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery/WMTS/1.0.0/{TileMatrixSet}/MapServer/tile/26120/{TileMatrix}/{TileRow}/{TileCol}')
m.add_layer(wmts)
```

Is that possible at all?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `ipyleaflet`, but I can post answer in plain JS if that would help you.

Comment: @TomazicM A plain JS answer would definitely help; the JS to python mapping is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the code that works for me in plain JS. I named wayback time slice parameter `timeId`.

```
var map = L.map('map', {
  center: [36, -114.96],
  zoom: 13
});

var template =
  'https://wayback.maptiles.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/world_imagery/wmts/1.0.0' + 
  '/{tileMatrixSet}/mapserver/tile/{timeId}/{z}/{y}/{x}';

var layer = L.tileLayer(template, {
  tileMatrixSet: 'default028mm',
  timeId: '26120',
}).addTo(map);
```

This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to `TomazicM` who proposed a pure Javascript [solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/451546/17409) I managed to access the WMTS service via `ipyleaflet`.

```py
from ipyleaflet import Map, TileLayer, WidgetControl
from ipywidgets import SelectionSlider

# Prepare a slider widget to navigate the version history of the basemap
# There doesn't seem to be any pattern between timeId and basemap date, so just a few couples manually extracted from
# https://wayback.maptiles.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/world_imagery/mapserver/wmts/1.0.0/wmtscapabilities.xml
date_timeId_mapping = [('2016-01-13', 3515),
                       ('2017-01-11', 577),
                       ('2018-01-08', 13161),
                       ('2019-01-09', 6036),
                       ('2020-01-08', 23001),
                       ('2021-01-13', 1049),
                       ('2022-01-12', 42663),
                       ('2023-01-11', 11475)]

# Date slider widget
wayback_slider = SelectionSlider(
    options=date_timeId_mapping,
    value=3515,
    description='Date',
    disabled=False,
    continuous_update=True,
    orientation='horizontal',
    readout=True
)
time_control = WidgetControl(widget=wayback_slider, position='topright')

# Connect tile layer (wayback, not yet defined) with slider value
def on_date_change(*args):
    wayback.url = 'https://wayback.maptiles.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/world_imagery/wmts/1.0.0/default028mm/mapserver/tile/%d/{z}/{y}/{x}' % wayback_slider.value
    wayback.redraw()
    
wayback_slider.observe(on_date_change, 'value')

# Prepare map, tilelayer and draw it
m = Map(center=(45.8107, 8.6288), zoom=16, scroll_wheel_zoom=True)
wayback = TileLayer(url='https://wayback.maptiles.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/world_imagery/wmts/1.0.0/default028mm/mapserver/tile/3515/{z}/{y}/{x}')
m.add_layer(wayback)
m.add_control(time_control)
m
```

Comment: besides the issue of _There doesn't seem to be any pattern between timeId and basemap date_,  when inspecting the images in https://livingatlas.arcgis.com/wayback, if you click on the map, it pops up a panel saying that the "version" of the image that you are looking at doesn't necessarily match with the date of the acquisition

Comment: @RodrigoE.Principe I also noticed that and reported it there -- https://github.com/vannizhang/wayback/issues/77